# How do I configure a WinForms TabControl inside the WindowsFormsHost WPF control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-forms-designer

How do I configure a WinForms TabControl inside the WindowsFormsHost WPF control, how can add TabPages using XAML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved encapsulating the TabControl and its tabpages inside a UserControl, then adding the UserControl to the WindowsFormsHost.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I understand it, you can create the WinForms `TabPages` in the same way you would create something normally in WPF with XAML. See [this](http://anoriginalidea.wordpress.com/2007/12/13/weird-science-defining-winforms-in-xaml/) page for an idea of what I mean.